# Condition within a switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is it possible to pass a variable to a switch statement, but conditionally! An example is below. I've tried something similar and it doesn't give any errors but then jumps straight to the default case regardless.

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = 2;

switch(foo == 1? foo : bar) {
    //cases
}
```

What is being checked is irrelevant, just wondered if this is possible to do as I find this more succinct than declaring another variable and doing the check before the switch! Cheers.

Comment: Yes, what you've posted [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/wms4bv9z/). Is your actual code somewhat different to this?

Comment: It's a little different, I basically split a string and check the 0th index in place of foo EDIT: turns out there was a semantic error, thanks for the help regardless!

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-base your question on that then and why that _isn't_ working, since it should.

Answer (score 1):

Wy don't declare `var` before switch ?

```
var foo = 1, 
    bar = 2,
    switchVar = (foo == 1) ? foo : bar;

switch(switchVar) {
   //cases
}
```

Comment: I was going to do this as a work around, I just wanted to know if it was possible that's all, as to me it seems more succinct.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good practise to put condition statement inside switch var.

Comment: Interesting.. could you perhaps suggest why? :)

Comment: It's cool to see that you find your variant easier to make sense of, whereas I find the first example easier to comprehend!